# $k\subset K$ field extension, $S$ transcendence base, then $K$ is algebraic extension of $k(S)$, why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, transcendence-theory

Terminology from Lang, Chapter VIII. 1.

$k\subset K$ field extension and $S$ transcendence base, then $K$ is algebraic over $k(S)$. Why is that so? Lang states as it is something trivial.

Surely we must exploit maximality of $S$ somewhere. I took an element $\alpha\in K$. If it is not algebraic, then it is transcendental over $k(S)$ which means it's also transcendental over $k$. So we can maybe create $S' = S\cup \{\alpha\}$ and show that it is algebraically independent over $k$, but how?

Also, is it always true then: adding transcendental element to an algebraically independent set keeps it algebraically independent?

Comment: The standard definition is that a set $S$ is a transcendence basis for a field extensions $k\subset K$ iff $S$ is algebraically independent and $k(S)\subset K$ is algebraic. Does Lang use some other definition?

Comment: No, Lang says that $k(S) \subset K$ algebraic follows from maximality of $S$, so it isn't a part of a definition. It needs to be proven (but he didn't prove it, he alluded it was trivial).

Comment: Please [edit] the definition you're working with in to your post.